# WFFM form tag has role attribute which is redundant

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

The  tag produced by WFFM contains the attribute role="form".

This is considered a redundant attribute and is causing issues for our site accessibility scan.

Here are the specifics from the accessibility scan...

*A WAI-ARIA attribute that has the exact same features as the HTML element it has been applied to has been used. The WAI-ARIA attribute is redundant since is doesn't provide the user with any additional information.*

Looking at the MVC form rendering that is installed with WFF, I see it points to the following class and method - Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.

Decompiling that class I can see their is a Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Constants class which contains several attributes of the rendered form element,  but not the role="form" attribute.

Would anyone know where Sitecore might be adding the attribute role to the form element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `Views\Form\EditorTemplates\FormViewModel.cshtml` file.

You will see there:

```cs
var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary()
{
    { "enctype", "multipart/form-data" },
    { "class", @Model.CssClass },
    { "id", Model.ClientId },
    { "role", "form" },
    { Constants.Wffm, Model.Item.ID }
};
```

and a bit lower those attributes (containing `form` role) are used in `BeginRouteForm` method:

```cs
using (Html.BeginRouteForm(routeName, queryString, FormMethod.Post, attributes))
```